# Why do the walls of the room disappear in this second shot?

Tags: production, editing, the-two-popes

In biographical drama movie *The Two Popes* (2019), there is a scene where Jorge Bergoglio argues with Father Yorio and Jalics in a closed room:

[image: two men talking] [image: two men talking, seen from behind]

In the second shot, Jurio leave the room with resentment, and we can see the
walls of the closed room disappear. It appears as if we were looking at that room's building frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When seeing this scene, my mind did not question it. I assumed it was a jump cut between the inside scene and the outside scene of the same building seconds later.